# JQuery - How to change a NaN to something else

Tags: jquery, nan

I have a function that displays a numerical total of various dropdowns.  If one of the dropdowns is set to # (the starting value), the resulting value is displayed as NaN.

I want to change how NaN is displayed on my page.  I want it to read "--" instead of "NaN".

Here is the function with variables and if/elses omitted:

```
function multiply() {
    $('#total').text((((beds * perhour) + (addbath)) * discount ));
}
```

How can I set the text to `--` instead of `NaN`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy fix is to use the fact that NaN is a falsy value

```
function multiply() {
    $('#total').text(((((beds * perhour) + (addbath)) * discount)) || 0);//instead of 0 you can pass any default value here like an empty string
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. Will update with check after timer runs out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**isNaN()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to compare if you got number or NaN, you can use [ternary conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to get assign `result` or string constant `"--"` to div.

```
result = isNaN((((beds * perhour) + (addbath)) * discount ))
$('#total').text(isNaN((result) ? "--" : result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function multiply() {
    var total = ((beds * perhour) + (addbath)) * discount; 
    $('#total').text(!isNan(total) ? total : '--');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use isNumeric function in jquery,

```
 $.isNumeric(NaN);    // false
```

Refer this, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/